# Predicting the number of nested circles

Tags: probability, geometry, random-variables, expected-value

Let's say we get $20000$ circles with random centers in a $200\times200$ square centered at the origin, with radii uniformly distributed over ${1,2,...,200}$. Call a circle "nested" in another if the first circle completely contains the second. What is the expected length of the largest "nesting" of all circles? Put another way, what is the longest chain of circles within circles you can expect?

Comment: Where is the problem from? And what are your thoughts?

Comment: Just a quick clarification: are you saying there are 100 circles of each radius or that the radius is a random integer between 1 and 200?

Comment: This seems to me unlikely to have an elegant analytical solution, but maybe someone will surprise me.  Have you tried a simulation?  Also: Are the centers also on the integer lattice points, or can they be at any arbitrary point inside the square?

Comment: @quasi This is a problem I came up with after my friend struggled with a similar issue in a simulation.

Comment: @automaticallyGenerated 100 circles of each radius. That's a much better way to say that, I'll update accordingly

Comment: @BrianTung I'll work on a simulation right now! Centers are at arbitrary points inside the square, though the other problem is equally interesting to me

Comment: @TreFox: I would not expect an exact symbolic answer to be achievable. I'd just settle for a simulation. Centers at lattice points offers more potential for an exact answer, but even with that simplification, I'd bet against an exact answer.

Comment: Are the circles guaranteed to be fully within the square?  One of radius $200$ must have its center at the center of the square.  That will lengthen the expected chain

Comment: @RossMillikan No, they are not guaranteed to be inside the square. Only their centers.

Comment: @TreFox: I think you'll find that even a simulation is a non-trivial task. Doable, but non-trivial. If you succeed, please update your post to show your results.

Comment: @TreFox: Have you considered first analyzing the $1$-dimensional analogue, using intervals instead of circles, with centers randomly chosen on the real number line in the interval $[-100,100]$? In fact, if you use integer centers, and dramatically reduce all the parameters, you should be able to get exact answers for some very low cases, via exhaustive enumeration. The results might show a pattern.